# System.nanoTime() in Java gives different running time for same inputs

Tags: java

I used the following code to measure the running time of my program,

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "agtacgtcatacgtctagtactacgttca";
    String b = "gtatccctagactsgtatcatacgtctat";
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    //This method call computes the Longest Common Sequence of the given 2 strings.
    System.out.println(LCS.Linear.computeLCS(a, b));
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Took "+(endTime - startTime) + " ns");
}
```

Sample Outputs for same input:

**Run 1:**

```
gtacctagctgtactacgtta
Took 1971471 ns
```

**Run 2:**

```
gtacctagctgtactacgtta
Took 2242336 ns
```

**Why is the difference in running time each time?**

**How to find the actual running time of that method call?**

Comment: Micro-benchmarking in Java is *much* harder than you think. See [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those running times are in the magnitude of 2 milliseconds! You can't expect them to be the same for two separate runs. From the documentation:

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but **not necessarily nanosecond accuracy**.

Micro benchmarks like these are extremely hard to get accurate figures for. You have several sources of nondeterminism:

- other processes on your computer
- JVM warmup
- JIT compilation
- garbage collection

to name a few. You should *at least* try to run your algorithm 10.000 times or so and take the average.

**Further reading:**

- [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)
- [OpenJDK jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)
- [Java Microbenchmarks](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks)

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to reliable measure time. I think it is less a Java problem, but more a question how to can ensure that the system does nothing beside executing your code.

I think the only real solution is to replace the measure but a series of measurement and use statistics. There are some frameworks for microbenchmarking that you should investigate. For instance:

- [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/)
- [Japex](https://japex.java.net/)

To make matters worse, even the JIT optimization of the JVM itself is non-deterministic, so when you restart the JVM and measure again, in general, the optimized code itself will differ.

There is a great talk from Joshua Bloch about the topic: [Performance Anxiety – on Performance Unpredictability, Its Measurement and Benchmarking](https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2010/12/10/joshua-bloch-performance-anxiety-on-unpredictability/) (link to [slides](http://wiki.jvmlangsummit.com/images/1/1d/PerformanceAnxiety2010.pdf))